# multer middleware does not recognize body of req

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, multer

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "public/images");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    console.log(req.body); // <- This will output null object
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage });
app.post("/api/upload", upload.single("file"), (req, res) => {
  try {
    return res.status(200).json(req.body);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Postman request:
[image]

Console output:

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>>SERVER STARTED<<<<<<<<<<<<<
(node:3741192) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Top-level use of w, wtimeout, j, and fsync is deprecated. Use writeConcern instead.
(node:3741192) DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead.
Connected to MongoDB
[Object: null prototype] {}
::1 - - [08/Jun/2021:12:11:21 +0000] "POST /api/upload HTTP/1.1" 200 23
```

My problem is that within:

```
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    console.log(req.body); // <- This will output null object
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  },
```

`req.body` is an empty object. But it shouldn't? In the postman request, I included a `name` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [multer documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#diskstorage):

> Note that req.body might not have been fully populated yet. It depends
> on the order that the client transmits fields and files to the server.

So changing the order in your postman form and putting `name` before `file` (you can simply drag/drop the row) will fix the issue.

Comment: It worked beautifully, thanks. But I was following a tutorial, and this is the order that the guy who did the tutorial used. It worked for him. Any reasons why the difference?

Comment: Good question, not sure what the reason could be, sorry.